# Create subclass of a model

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

In my application, I have a model `Comment` which has a relationship `author` with a model `User`.

To speak in Java terms, this model `User` is an abstract class: the model instances are either of type `Student` or `Teacher`. To this end, the model `User` has an attribute `type`. So the structure is as follows:

```
App.Comment = DS.Model.extend({
    author: DS.belongsTo('user'),
    ...
});
```

and

```
App.User = DS.Model.extend({
    type: DS.attr('string'),
    ...
});

App.Student = App.User.extend({
    ...
});

App.Teacher = App.User.extend({
    ...
});
```

Through a REST API I receive a list of `Comment`'s, including their respective `author`'s.

By default, for each author, Ember will create an instance of the `User` model.

However, instead I would like it to create either a `Student` or a `Teacher`, depending on the `type` attribute in the request response.

What would be the best way to achieve this? Somewhere I should be able to override a function that maps JSON keys to Ember models.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I found it. It turns out Ember has support for polymorphic models so I solved it easily by adding `{polymorphic: true}` to the `author` relationship.

```
App.Comment = DS.Model.extend({
    author: DS.belongsTo('user', { polymorphic: true }),
    ...
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I would try overriding the serializer for App.Comment.  You can find some example documentation [here](https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/master/TRANSITION.md#per-type-serializers).